# Strange Firewall Placement?

Tags: firewall

I joint a company recently and manager given me a network design. I found that the network design is a bit different than normal cases. As I'm newbie on firewall. Does the below setting proper? They seems not concern about the 
Outbound traffic: 
PC -> Switch -> Firewall -> Router OR PC -> Switch -> Router

But I doubt on the inbound traffic:

Router -> ***Switch*** -> Firewall..... Any potential risk for this setting? thank you very much!!!

Per my understanding, a normal design is:

Internet -> Firewall -> Switch -> PC / Server

My Company Firewall:

[image]

Comment: This is missing information, especially what sort of VLANs are set up on the switch.

Comment: There is no VLAN ...So this is a bit different than my learning, thank you!

Comment: If there are no VLAN's on the switch or no port isolation isolating the router from the rest of the ports then that seems like kind of a bad design to me. You said you can ping the router directly from your computer but that shouldn't be the case. The router and your computer are on different subnets. You can ping the router but the traffic is going through the firewall to get there. Run a trace route to the router from your computer and you should see it traverse the firewall. As it stands though, I don't see the effectiveness of this particular setup.

Answer (score 1):

> Router -> Switch -> Firewall..... Any potential risk for this setting?

You mean besides the dozens of reasons this may have? I have something similar.

Router -> switch -> switch <-> Firewall.

The first router is controlled by the ISP. The switch handles all the house traffic (and the internet is coming through a specific VLAN). The next swith does server room distribution (again internet on a specific VLAN) and then the firewall handles the firewalling (and goes back to the switch on different vlan's for different internal networks.

In your diagram I would have a look at the switch - they SHOULD have the ports separated so that use PC's never see or can talk to the router. It is unusual, but not extremely so - one advantage is having a port available to plug in a laptop before the firewall for testing.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your reply. Since there is no VLAN define, there are some concern is that will the "unwanted" traffic spread out on the switch before reaching the Firewall. You can see the next hop from Internet is Switch, where is all internal computers interconnected. thank you!!

Comment: Yes and no. As i said - the switch may well be configurable enough to isolate ports into different groups. If that happens no VLAN are needed.

Comment: Thank you for you reply Tom. I'm not pretty sure if there is some group or security control, but I could ping to the router directly from my computer which connected to same switch. In case there is no security isolation, is it a big concern? thank you!

Comment: Depending on IP addresses - it is. A simple router level NAT setup is enough security, though, for smaller setups. But then the question is - what the **** is the firewall for? I mean, enable NAT on router, plug machines behind it = good enough for small shop. But then you simply have no need for a firewall. This REALLY smells like an incompetently botched setup with a firewall that is never used.

Comment: Hi Tom, so this design might not the best practice in general but no high risk from internet attack? Thank you!

Comment: Well, that design is ridiculous because the firewall makes no sense.  So that part just is - well, nonsensical. Having machines directly behind a NAT router is actually best practice for small easy setups. If you combine that with modern windows integrated firewall you get quite a security - definitely enough for example a small graphics design office with maybe 10 machines. Best thing is - you do that without a lot of cost and maintenance. On top, unless the firewall is high end, the router should be able to do that. My Mikrotik routers can handle what most people consider firewalls easily.

Comment: Too bad...the design is using in a company with 600+ computers...

Comment: Well, then someone would have to answer questions. Mostly about why wasting money on a not used firewall? Because that is what it seems to be.